# One-Step estimators for non-linear regression

Tags: econometrics, nonlinear-regression

'Disclosure': This question is also asked in the economics.stack community, under the tag of Econometrics, with same title. I'm not sure if it's too technical for that community.

Let's suppose I have $\sqrt{N}$-consistent estimate, $\beta^{*}$(vector, but couldn't put it in bold), then doing the Gauss-Newton Regression, i.e. $\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})=D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{v}$.

Then we obtain the estimate $\mathbf{\hat b}=\left(D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})^T D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})\right)^{-1}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*}))$.

By adding this last estimate to $\beta^{*}$, we get the one-step estimator $\bar\beta=\beta^{*}+\mathbf{\hat b}$.

My first question is how the initial estimate is obtained? Do we use the usual method for estimations in this setting (Quasi-Newton methods, etc.)?

Second, how do we prove that this one-step estimator is asymptotically efficient?

I'm following Davidson and Mackinnon (2008) book, but the way they 'derive' it is not really a proof.

So, by trying to mimic their line of reasoning I've done the following:

From a Taylor Expansion/Mean-Value theorem,
$$n^{-1/2}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*}))=n^{-1/2}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta_0)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta_0))+\underbrace{\left(o_p(1)-n^{-1}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta)^TD_\mathbf{x}(\beta)\right)}_{\Delta(\beta)}n^{-1/2}(\beta^{*}-\beta_0)$$, where $\beta_0$ is the DGP value of beta, and we've done an abuse of notation by not specifying a different beta for each component of $\Delta(\beta)$. See the answers to [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/proving-the-asymptotic-normality-of-th-non-linear-least-squares-estimator), if you're interested in more details on this expansion.

Also, we know from the previous link, that for the Non-linear Least Squares estimator $\hat\beta$, we have $n^{-1/2}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)=-\Delta(\beta)^{-1}n^{-1/2}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta_0)^T\mathbf{u}$.

Hence we can conclude

$n^{-1/2}(\beta^{*}-\beta_0)=\Delta(\beta)^{-1}n^{-1/2}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*}))+n^{-1/2}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)$, implying that

$n^{-1/2}(\beta^{*}-\hat\beta)=\Delta(\beta)^{-1}n^{-1/2}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta^{*}))$.

By definition, and some usual assumptions, we know that $plim \Delta(\beta)=S_{D_\mathbf{x}^TD_\mathbf{x}}$.

And I'm stuck here, because what the book does is not translatable when I try be formal in the derivation. So, what should I do to prove that the one-step estimator is efficient?